# iOS app that change whole app color theme (background, uibutton, icons color...) base on user selection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a requirement to make application that has color theme base on user selection
User selects an color at begining (in 8 available colors), that color will be applied for the whole app (background color, buttons, icons ....)

If I create images for each color, the app will have lots of images and can be heavy in size, and that approach not seem to be good one.

I tried to import images with 1 color and then change images color according to user-selected color, but got problem with some controls like slider, and also the image that is changed does not look good as photoshop one

Would u plz help me with good approach for this?

Comment: Check UIAppereance protocol. I think this is the best approach here. Regarding the quality, make sure the Photoshop images don't contain some other effects like shadow/stroke/ etc.

Comment: Would u plz give more details how to use UIAppearance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all the images one color (black probably), then let the user pick a color and save it to user defaults. Link all items that need to get the theme to the color from the user defaults. Then use the tintColor property of the UIImageView to themefy your app.

**Method to tint any UIImageView**:

```
- (void)tintImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView withTint:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    imageView.image = [imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

    [imageView setTintColor:tintColor];
}
```

**Example use to tint Button:**

```
[self tintImageView:self.button.imageView withTint:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

**Example use to tint UIImageView:**

```
[self tintImageView:self.imageView withTint:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: Would u plz show me how to change color of custom button with background image (I want to change the image color, not color of default button) using tintColor?

Comment: Modified the answer. This will tint the imageView of the button (not the button)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried to change the button, it did change, but when I click on the button, it showed the original image. Here's my code: UIButton *bt = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 350, 20, 20)];
    [bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_drag"] forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;
    [self tintImageView:bt.imageView withTint:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:bt];

Answer (score 2):

If you're using iOS7 you can take advantage of the tintColor property.
For images you need to be sure they are created using template option.
Please checkout this clear tutorial that will guide you to apply themes to different kind of controls in your app: [Theming iOS Applications](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/steven-beyers/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming)

You could probably be interested in trying Pixate Freestyle too, which basically allow you to apply styles like css does to your iOS app, that a pretty cool tool and I've found it very easy to use too.

Comment: Thanks. But i'm not sure how to use tintColor correctly. And would u plz explain about "template option"?

Comment: I would definitely go with Pixate Freestyle. Keep all the ugly UI customizations out of your code.